# Multiple programs using one or multiple config file

Tags: c++, linux, configuration, config

I have a embedded device with a custom linux built with yocto.
On this device are multiple programs:

- reading data from sensors
- converting the data into a given format
- response to udp-requests
- ...

many of the programs need some configuration, like:

- how many samples to read
- which format to convert
- which udp-port
- ...

My Question is now, what is the best way to store these settings?

Is it better to store all of them in just one file?
(When replacing the device, I would only have to change one file.)

Or is it better to make a config-file for each program?

Comment: MAYBE saving encoded information on a single file would be a nice option.

Comment: Are you developing all these applications yourself? Or are they applications developed by others? If the latter, it might be a lot of work to modify their source code so they use your preferred choice of configuration file syntax.

Comment: @CiaranMcHale I'm developing all of them on my own. They are all pretty simple/short, it should be not that much work to modify them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you arrange for each application to obtain its configuration variables from a named *scope* within a named *file*, for example, you might start applications *app1*, *app2* and *app3* as follows:

```
app1 -cfg common.cfg -scope app1
app2 -cfg common.cfg -scope app2
app3 -cfg common.cfg -scope app3
```

The above instructs each application to read its configuration variables from an application-specific scope within a common configuration file. If you change your mind, and decide it is best for each application to have its own configuration file, then you can achieve this by just changing the `-cfg <file.cfg>` command-line options, to yield:

```
app1 -cfg app1.cfg -scope app1
app2 -cfg app2.cfg -scope app2
app3 -cfg app3.cfg -scope app3
```

You should find it easy to map the concept of a *scope* to the realities of your preferred configuration file format. For example, in XML, a *scope* refers to an XML element.

If you do not already have a preferred configuration-file syntax, then you might want to look at the [Config4*](http://www.config4star.org/) configuration-file parser (available in C++ and Java, and developed by me). It directly supports what I describe above. Reading Chapter 2 (syntax overview) and Chapter 3 (API overview) of the *Config4* Getting Started Guide*, should be enough to help you make an informed decision about whether it fits your needs.